# epoch timestamp converter with millennia range, python

Tags: python

is there an epoch time converter that can deal with millennia?

```
time.gmtime(1000 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
```

throws

```
ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t
```

Comment: This will work fine on a 64bit platform using 64bit libraries. It will fail (as you found) on a 32-bit platform

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at least on Windows (using Windows 7 here).  What platform are you using?

```
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71605, Apr 14 2009, 22:40:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> time.gmtime(1000*365*24*60*60)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2969, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=3, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=123, tm_isdst=0)
```

Also, even on Linux you should be able to do some processing of dates well beyond 2038 using the [datetime module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#module-datetime).  The docs say MAXYEAR is 9999 for that module:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now().replace(year=1000+1971)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2971, 12, 29, 11, 43, 20, 727000)
>>> dt.timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2971, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=29, tm_hour=11, tm_min=41, tm_sec=16, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=363, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Of course, that last call probably won't work on Linux if the `time.gmtime()` call is failing, but since you haven't really said what you want to do with the date maybe this is sufficient for now.

Comment: i'm on macosx.

strangely it does allow

"datetime.datetime(2971, 12, 29, 11, 43, 20, 727000)"

without error.

Comment: @_jeremy, nothing strange about that, as the datetime object should support it on all platforms.  It's the `.timetuple()` call I expect would fail wherever the `time.gmtime()` call fails.